# How Read Email With Tables Java Code?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, mime-types

I am trying to read email body from outlook with following java code. How do I read properly if the email contains table? 
Code used is

```
  // Methods to get Email message content.
  private String getTextFromMessage(Message message) throws Exception {
    String result = "";
    if (message.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
      result = message.getContent().toString();
    } else if (message.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
      MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart)message.getContent();
      result = getTextFromMimeMultipart(mimeMultipart);
    }
    result = removeHyperTextContent(result);
    return result;
  }

  private String getTextFromMimeMultipart(MimeMultipart mimeMultipart) throws Exception
  {
    String result = "";
    int count = mimeMultipart.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
      if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
        result = result + "\n" + bodyPart. getContent();
        break; }
      if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/html")) {
        String html = (String)bodyPart.getContent();
        result = result + "\n" + html;
      } else if ((bodyPart.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart)) {
        result = result + getTextFromMimeMultipart((MimeMultipart)bodyPart.getContent());
        break; //This is added to break after recursive call, otherwise it fetches the content from next MultiPart.
      }
    }
    result = removeHyperTextContent(result);
    return result;
  }
```

[1. Body of original body text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIsod.png)
[2 . Out put string I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxdUy.png)

Comment: It's unclear in the question what output you're looking for. It looks like you're getting the exact output of the tables. If you're outputting the email as a string, that's as good as it's gonna get.

Comment: .Thank you for your reply.I want to show it entire message as it is to the user on browser. How can I do that? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this JavaMail FAQ entry will help you find the [main message body](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#mainbody) in an email message.

In your code, you're preferring the text/plain content over the text/html content.  Tables may not be formatted nicely in the text/plain content, but it depends on the mailer being used.  The text/html content will have all the information about the table, but you'll need something that parses html to be able to extract the table information in a form you can use.

It's not clear to me what you want to do with the table once you extract it.  If you're displaying the result as html in a browser, having the original html table may be exactly what you need.